# Edit src strings of js files after grunt-php2html

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, gruntjs, php2html

I am using [grunt-php2html](https://github.com/bezoerb/grunt-php2html) to compile my development `*.php` files into 'client-ready' `*.html` ones and it's working great.

I tend to have unminified files in the development version (php), and uglified ones in html. I uglify by grunt dynamically, so my files get `.min.` appended to their filenames.

By default the resulting html files will still have the filenames without `.min.` in them, so, I have to replace `.js` to `.min.js` via options, like so:

```
php2html: {
    options: {
        process: function(response, callback) {
            callback(response.replace(/\.js/g, '.min.js'));
        }
    }
}
```

However I see the drawbacks of such a solution, as the string `.js` may appear not only in the `src` attribute of the `script` tag, but also in the body text, where of course I'd like it to remain untouched.

So my question is, how am I to write a regular expression so that it targeted only *real* `script` tags. If anybody has any advice or alternative solution, I'd be very glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for complex `regular expression`, I'd suggest being specific and get advantage of the path to the JS folder in which all your minified JS files are.

This could be an example:

```
var response = 'some .js here ... <script src="js/path/something.js"></script> another .js here';
var res = response.replace(/(src=\"js\/path\/\w*)\.js/g, '$1.min.js');
```

Note the usage of `$1` which gets the value of the first group (enclosed in parenthesis) to keep/maintain from the regular expression.

Comment: My script files are either in the `scripts` directory or in the `scripts/libs` directory, so having `/(src="scripts(\/|\/libs\/)\w*)\.js/g` as a matcher seems to do the thing. I hope I'll never have `scripts/foo.js` in my body text :) Thanks for the `$1` thing too.

Comment: BTW, had to change the regExp further, as some files may contain not just alphanumeric characters, but also a dot and a hyphen, so the current version I have is as follows: `/(src="scripts(\/|\/libs\/)[A-Za-z0-9_\.-]*)\.js/g`